Facebook API: You couldn't create the client business on behalf your client successfully
This is my c# project. I was trying to create an API to allow user to add their business into my Business Facebook Partner. Below is my code which how to add into my Facebook Business Partner. When i trying to add the user into my Facebook Business Partner section, it show me this error message:
{"error":{"message":"You couldn't create the client business on behalf your client successfully","type":"OAuthException","code":42004,"error_subcode":1752286,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Fail to create business relationship aggregator on behalf of client","error_user_msg":"Business On-Behalf-Of creation fails because the app is in dev mode and the Business On-Behalf-Of creator is not an admin of both client business and partner business."}}

Below is my code how to add the user into my Facebook Business Partner:
private async Task<bool> AddPartnerToBusinessAsync(string partnerBusinessId, string clientBusinessId, string accessToken)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var requestUrl = $"https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/{partnerBusinessId}/managed_businesses";
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("existing_client_business_id", clientBusinessId),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("access_token", accessToken)
        });

        var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUrl, content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Log or handle the error
            var errorResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"Facebook API Error: {response.StatusCode} - {errorResponse}");

            // Handle specific errors
            var errorData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(errorResponse);
            var errorCode = (int)errorData.error.code;
            var errorSubcode = (int)errorData.error.error_subcode;

            if (errorCode == 42004 && errorSubcode == 1752286)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Business On-Behalf-Of creation fails because the app is in dev mode and the user is not an admin of both client business and partner business.");
                // Provide additional guidance or steps to the user
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}

Note: The Apps is still in development mode. So i want to try if whether can add the user into my Facebook Business Partner then only can deploy to live.
